# "В последнее время" или "последнее время"

Tags: грамматика

I've seen expressions like this, with, and without the **"в"**

**В первый раз— Я в первый раз здесь.**

**Первый раз — Я первый раз здесь.**

**В последнее время— я в последнее время стала очень ленивой."**

**Последнее время— я последнее время стала очень нервной."**

Is there a difference in meaning?

Comment: every of the variants are correct, to me they sound like synonyms

Comment: then what doe the в do here? or is it just historical?

Comment: The same question: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2750/%D0%92-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7 "в первый раз" is older. In these examples (I think) "в первый раз" is more bookish, and "первый раз" is more colloquial.

Comment: It's the same as: It's my first time in here. I'm here for the first time
You can say either way.

Comment: I don't know, if I knew anything more significant, I would have posted an answer. But from the point of an ordinary native speaker I can assure you, that some 99% of the native speakers do not see any difference between these variants

Comment: In these cases, "в" is omitted in the same way as in "it is" -> "it's".

Answer (score 1):

Although the variants omitting "в" are widely used they are colloquial and grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

В первый раз— Я в первый раз здесь.
Первый раз — Я первый раз здесь.

they are both correct but second is more common. And first is more emotional a little bit.

And I've not got it

В последнее время— я в последнее время стала очень ленивой."

Последнее раз— я в последнее время стала очень нервной."

Comment: "Последнее раз" в Вашем ответе что означает?